# Cannot crawl those tweets which contains hashag

Tags: java, web-scraping, web-crawler, twitter4j

I use twitter4j to crawl twitter but I am facing a very funny error:

when I try to crawl twitter4j for all tweets wiich contains hashtag(so my serach term would be just #),  everything  returns with and without hashtag but I just want to get those tweets that contain hashtag,
 here is my code:

```
        **String query = "#";
        System.out.println("[Current query is \"" + query + "\"]");
        // Query settings
        twitterQuery = new Query(query);
        // Result per page
        twitterQuery.setCount(resultPerPage);
        // Language code
        twitterQuery.setLang(lang);
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(twitterQuery);
    List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();**
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Fyi, in case you only saw my initial answer where I said it might not be possible, I now made an edit which gives a suggestion that I think may work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that the Twitter4J library uses the Twitter API. Looking at the [Twitter Search API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) it says to try constructing a query in the [Twitter Advanced Search web page](https://twitter.com/search-advanced) first.

I was neither able to search for tweets containing a hash sign, nor to search for tweets containing a wildcard hashtag.

This does not seem to be well documented anywhere, but after playing around with it for a while, it looks like you might be able to use `filter:hashtags` in the query.